# Dodge Ram truck backfired and died after fueling

Tags: engine, dodge, ram, backfire

We got gas and right after we pulled out of the station the truck backfired sputtered and died. We kept trying to start it back when it finally started it backfired sputtered and died again. What can be the cause of this

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If it was running before you pulled into the gas station and it ran like crap after, I'm thinking you got bad gas. If this isn't a gas station you usually use, it very well could be something like this.

Comment: Did you fill the tank all the way up?

Answer (score 1):

I would check the EVAP system for problems.

[image]

You can start getting issues when filling up with fuel if there is an issue with the evap system.  Fuel vapours from the tank are collected in a charcoal canister and are burned when the engine is running and up to temperature.  If when filling up a large amount of fuel got into the canister and then past the purge valve then the engine can end up flooded with fuel.

See more info [here](https://www.samarins.com/glossary/purge-valve.html)